# laravel 5.8 Auth/RegisterController custom redirect on validation failure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8, I have a single page that has both the Registration and Login forms (2 separate forms posting to the respective endpoints/controllers)

My Registration Form posts to the Auth/RegistrationController as provided by Lavarel Auth.

I would like to change the behaviour so that on an unsuccessful registration attempt it will add an additional parameter to redirect url so I know which form to apply to validation feedback too.

I'm already aware of the redirectTo variable this appears to be for successful requests though

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `Auth/RegistrationController::register` method, take a look at the default code provided by the framework and adjust it to your needs something like this:

```
public function register(Request $request) {

    if ($this->validator($request->all())->fails()) {
        return redirect('/foo?bar=1');
    }

    // Copy the default behaviour here
    ...
    // or you can just
    return parent::register($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply overwrite parent function to create new user in same

> Auth/RegistrationController create new method as

```
  /**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Here, in '$data' variable you will get all of the parameters which you have passed through form.

For error checking you can just check for,

> Laravel global error variable $errors is null or not

```
  /**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if(!empty($errors)){
        if($data['form'] == 'form_1'){
            $redirectTo = 'fitst_form' 
        }
        else if($data['form'] == 'form_2'){
            $redirectTo = 'second_form' 
        }
    }
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I don't think you've understood my question, I want to conditionally redirect based on an unsuccessful registration. Your answer is based on .valid registration

Comment: what do you mean by unsuccessful registration??

Comment: there is a default validation rule in laravel . called 'unique'.. you can use it like ====   Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users']
        ]);

Comment: I'm still not sure, we're pushing at the right problem here. Perhaps I should explain in more detail ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set register method in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

protected function register(Request $request)
{

$errors = ['error'=>'yout errors list];
   if(!empty($errors)){
       return redirect()->route('/register-errorpage')->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
   }
}